# How would two empty divs with only margins collapse?

Tags: html, css

How would two empty divs with only margins collapse?

html file:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS File:

```
#div1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> You will have only 30px margin at the end

You are facing two kind of margin collpasing. Since each div is empty, its top margin and bottom margin will collapse so for the first one we will have `20px` and for the second one `30px`. Then those margin will also collapse together and will end with only `30px`.

You can verify this by checking the height of the html element and you will see this:

```css
#div1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

[image]

From the [sepcification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> top and bottom margins of a box that does not establish a new block
>   formatting context and that has zero computed 'min-height', zero or
>   'auto' computed 'height', and no in-flow children

And

> bottom margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following
>   sibling

---

As a side note, the body has also a default margin (`8px`) collapsing with other other margin following this rule:

> top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child

And

> bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent
>   if the parent has 'auto' computed height

Comment: why is Chrome devtools showing 0 height for both divs?

Comment: @Django102 simply becasue they are empty divs :) there is nothing inside, not even a whitespace

Comment: Oh sorry @Temani I meant how do I verify the total margin using devtools? I tried what you said "You can verify this by checking the height of the html element".

Comment: @Django102 ah, Yes you need to check the height of the html element since it's the parent element that will hold all the content, so all the margin will collapse and at the end you will have one 30px margin inside the html thus the height of the html is 30px [click on the html element and check its height]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to ask what this would look like, you can simply add borders to the divs to give you an idea of what is happening.

Since you've set a margin to both divs, there will be a margin separating the two. However, since the divs are empty they will have no height.

You can check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rt1y0v4j/

You can also use chrome dev tools to inspect the element by hitting `cmd-shift-C` on Mac or `ctrl-shift-C` on Windows/Linux.  Hovering over the elements in devtools should give you a visual confirmation that these divs are adhering to the specified margins.

Comment: whats the margin between the two divs?

Comment: adding border will change the behavior completely

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve here: the border gives the divs height ** Without it, the net margin will be the greatest margin: 30px. Which, hopefully you saw in devtools, but @Temani describes in their answer.